# jQuery and Bootstrap text field that filters dropdown when button is clicked

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a search box.  When the user hits search, depending on the characters entered, it displays matching results in a dropdown that can be selected. WHen the user selects the item, it populates in the input box for form submittal.  See picture below of what I need.  I am using jQuery and Bootsrap but I cant seem to get it to go.

Heres my code.  I was also toggling the dropdown using jquery which worked.

```
<input list="list" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for item" name="item-search" id="item-search"><span class="input-group-btn"><button class="btn" id="apply-btn" type="button">Apply</button></span>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" id="list-dropdown-items"></ul>
<li><a value="value1">value1</a></li>
<li><a value="value2">value2</a></li>
<li><a value="value3">value3</a></li>
<li><a value="value4">value4</a></li>
<li><a value="value5">value5</a></li>
<li><a value="value6">value6</a></li>
```

[textbox with dropdown filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMhWw.png)

Comment: You can try something like https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Answer (score 0):

You could try out this:

https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

This is a much more powerful plugin for search boxes/dropdowns and has a lot of functionality. I have been using it for the project I'm working on and it's incredibly useful for filtering.